# Why datetime format is not intepreted correctly with pandas apply()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to apply a function on my pandas dataframe with `pandas.apply()` function. But I encounter a problem with the datetime format when I try to assign datetime variable form another column of that dataframe to another.

```
def arr_time(x):
  if x.CRS_DEP_TIME > x.CRS_ARR_TIME:
     x['CRS_ARR_DATE'] = x.FL_DATE + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit="D")
     x['CRS_ARR_HH'] = x.CRS_DEP_TIME // 100
     x['CRS_ARR_MM'] = x.CRS_DEP_TIME % 100

     x['ACT_ARR_DATE'] = x.FL_DATE + pd.to_timedelta(1, unit="D")
     x['ACT_ARR_HH'] = x.CRS_DEP_TIME // 100
     x['ACT_ARR_MM'] = x.CRS_DEP_TIME % 100
  else:
     x['CRS_ARR_DATE'] = x.FL_DATE
     x['CRS_ARR_HH'] = x.CRS_DEP_TIME // 100
     x['CRS_ARR_MM'] = x.CRS_DEP_TIME % 100

     x['ACT_ARR_DATE'] = x.FL_DATE # it is already with the datetime format
     print(x.FL_DATE) # works perfectly 2019-01-03
     x['ACT_ARR_HH'] = x.CRS_DEP_TIME // 100
     x['ACT_ARR_MM'] = x.CRS_DEP_TIME % 100

  return

 airline = airline.apply(arr_time, axis=1)
 airline.CRS_ARR_DATE.astype('datetime64[ns]') # Try to reconvert int64 into datetime64 but it does not have any effect
 airline.ACT_ARR_DATE.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

The problem is values inside X['CRS_ARR_DATE'] for instance are not in datetime format but have the following form:

```
0  1480550400000000000          
1  1480550400000000000          
2  1480550400000000000
```

results of dataframe info:

```
...
ACT_DEP_HH               5 non-null float64
CRS_ARR_DATE             5 non-null int64
ACT_ARR_DATE             5 non-null int64
CRS_ARR_HH               5 non-null int64
CRS_ARR_MM               5 non-null int64
ACT_ARR_HH               5 non-null int64
ACT_ARR_MM               5 non-null int64
```

Thus during the apply function pandas convert a `datetime64[ns]` object into a `int64` and I do not why.

Comment: `airline.CRS_ARR_DATE.astype('datetime64[ns]') # does not have any effect` why _would_ it have any effect, since you've already done `apply` before that point? You haven't shown any traceback, but it's not logical that you can somehow fix the problem by picking the time format after the failed lines of code.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I checked the dataframe info and during the `apply` function new variables created like `CRS_ARR_DATE` have type int64 instead of `datetime64[ns]`. Thus while assigning `x.FL_DATE` pandas convert datetime object into an integer and I do not why.